# iis 7 url rewrite redirect file in directory

Tags: iis-7, redirect

I am trying to redirect a url of the form

```
http://localhost:8065/Documents/anything.pdf
```

I want this to go to a different site (with the same filename but I can't even get it to go to the other site). Here's my script:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Archibald" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^/documents/.+\.(?:pdf)$" />
        <action type="Redirect" url="http:\\www.dorkingsos.org.uk" />
        <conditions>
        </conditions>
      </rule>
 </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Why doesn't it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to match all files and add a condition for PATH_INFO

```
<rule name="Archibald" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
   <match url=".*" />
   <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.dorkingsos.org.uk/pdfs/{C:1}" />
   <conditions>
      <add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="^/documents/(.*.pdf)$" />
    </conditions>
</rule>
```